# How to get value from javascript alert to textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The value must be retrived from javascript alert to textbox without losing runat="server".
code as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btn-group > button.btn").on("click", function () {
        var name = this.innerHTML; ;
        $('#TextBox1').html(name); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn-group > button.btn").on("click", function () {
            var name = this.innerHTML; ;
    // Use `val()` instead of html
    // Use `ClientID ` to use textbox generated id in javascript
            $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>').val(name); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The textbox gets added space before value and in between also, How to clear it @AnantDabhi

Comment: use $.trim   for E.g  :            ` $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>').val($.trim(name)); `

Comment: Sorry for disturbing @ AnantDabhi . My another question is related to above question,  i want to get button value to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TextBox1').val(name);
```

Use the [value](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the content of the text box